# Generics: constraints on nullable types

Tags: c#, generics

The following doesn't compile

```
public static T Retrieve<T>(this NameValueCollection collection, String key) where T : Object
{

    if (collection.AllKeys.Contains(key))
    {
        try
        {
            val = (T)Convert.ChangeType((object)collection[key], typeof(T));
        }
        catch { }
    }

    return val;            
}
```

because the Constraint cannot be the object class.  So is there a way to contrain T for anything that can be set to a null?

Comment: One thing to realize is that where T : Object means T has no constraint. ValueTypes are subclasses of Object. Rex M's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
where T : class
```

Your current constraint, `where T : Object` says "anything which is or inherits from System.Object", which is: everything. All types, including Int32 and String, inherit from System.Object. So constraining on Object would do nothing.

Edit: as usual, Eric shines a light on this [in a far more accurate way](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx):

> "in C# every type derives from object". Not true! The way to correct this myth is to simply replace "derives from" with "is convertible to", and to ignore pointer types: **every non-pointer type in C# is convertible to object.**

Comment: I just tried it and it gives you the four object methods: GetType, GetHashCode, ToString and Equals. Bad day yesterday, bunch of stupid posts, sorry.

Comment: It's actually a myth that all types inherit from object: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx -- However, your point is well taken. The reason we do not allow a constraint to object is because it is already the case that all type arguments must be convertible to object, so this is a constraint that means nothing, and is therefore probably an error.

Comment: This will not allow a nullable value type for T though, and he wants "anything that can be set to a `null`".

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to constrain your generic argument purely to a nullable type. You can easily constrain it to a reference type (as in previous answer), but, while all reference types are nullable, not all nullables are reference types.